# Is the max function limited to work only with a list of length 9?

Tags: python

```py
list= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' ,'11']
print( "Max value element : ", max(list))
```

o/p: 9
Why I am getting such error?

Comment: This is because they are strings, which are sorted by first character - `'11' < '9'`.

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

As your list contains `string` elements, they are sorted by lexicographic order, where `11` < `9` as you look from first char to last char, what you want is

```
# don't use built-in 'list' name
values = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' ,'11']
```

1. Use the values once, just to get the max :

   ```
   print( "Max value element : ", max(values,key=int))
   ```
2. Parse to list of int, and reuse it after

   ```
   values = list(map(int, values))
   print( "Max value element : ", max(values))
   ```

Comment: You can use `max(map(int,values))`. There no need to cast it into `list` explicitly.

Comment: @Ch3steR yep, but is the OP want to use the values again, it should be wrapped

Comment: Agreed. If he doesn't want to change the original list OP can always use `max(values,key=int)`. Nice answer so upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Lexicographically, `'9' > '1'`, so `'9'` will be judged as 'bigger' than `11`, in the same way that a word starting with `'z'` will be 'bigger' than a word starting with `'a'`.

You can keep your list the same and compare them as integers by adding a key for `max()`:

```
print("Max value element: ", max(lst, key=int))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of string, not integers.

To convert the list of strings to integers try

```
int_list = [int(el) for el in list]
```

Then your code will produce the correct result (11)